# Estimating self-discharge rate of ceramic capacitors from datasheet values DF and ESR

Tags: capacitor, theory

I'm trying to make an estimate for self-discharge rate of a typical small capacitor, such as 0.1 uF ceramic capacitor.  Horowitz and Hill says "A better measure of loss at low frequencies is Dissipation Factor [...] the low-frequency loss mechanism is dielectric loss, not metallic resistivity." (*Art of Electronics, the X Chapters*, p36).

Kemet's datasheet for one of its most common parts  [C0805C104K5RACTU](https://search.kemet.com/download/specsheet/C0805C104K5RACTU) (0.1 μF, 10%, 50 VDC, X7R) says:

- Dissipation factor: 2.5% 1 kHz 1.0 Vrms
- ESR at 100 Hz: ~150 Ω (The ESR graph only goes down to 100 Hz.)

Can we use these values to estimate the decay time to say 1% of original?  Following the capacitor charging rule, *V = e<sup>-t/RC</sup>*, I'm hoping for something like *t ≈ 5RC*, but don't see what to use for R.

Am I chasing rainbows or is there a simple way to estimate this?

A test circuit would be this: after C1 is completely charged, we disconnect from the charging circuit and measure the V<sub>output</sub>.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flPTke.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

> *I'm trying to make an estimate for self-discharge rate of a typical small capacitor*

You should read the [extended data sheet](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_C1002_X7R_SMD.pdf) and look at the insulation resistance on page 14: -

[image]

So, I calculate the insulation resistance to be 10 GΩ using their guidance. This will determine the typical CR decay time (1000 seconds for a 100 nF capacitor).

What you linked to is what Kemet call their spec sheet.

> *after C1 is completely charged, we disconnect from the charging
> circuit and measure the V<sub>output</sub>.*

Most typical multimeters will have a 10 MΩ voltage measuring input resistance and, this would be a thousand times lower than the insulation resistance = ineffective test.

> *Estimating self-discharge rate of ceramic capacitors from datasheet
> values DF and ESR*

Dissipation factor is for AC scenarios and at DC, this would imply an infinite resistance because reactance would be infinite (\$D.F. = \frac{R_S}{X_C}\$). Insulation resistance takes over at very low frequencies because it becomes dominant.

Comment: Thanks as always for such a swift and helpful answer.  I believe there's an error though in that note 2 for 0805 says "For Cap value 0.1uF (≤ 50V ) IR should be calculated under 500 mohms or 10GOhm", giving 5 GΩ, which matches that given in the spec sheet.  I'm not sure why you're suggest measuring resistance; I'm speaking about the time until the voltage is at 1% of original.

Comment: OK, I missed that (not a big difference actually). I'm not suggesting measuring resistance; I'm explaining that using a DVM to measure discharge **voltage** would be ineffective because it's input impedance is highly likely to be far too low and, it will discharge the capacitor quite rapidly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I didn't understand you meant discharging during the measurement.  Yes, clearly you can't leave any ordinary meter connected.

Comment: You also need to look at things like switch resistance when open, as it might well be in Gohm region.

Comment: @jonathanjo if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: Especially after reading comment from colintd, I'm wondering about the relative importance of C's insulation resistance, PCB resistance, atmospheric and so on, and waiting a little while to see if anyone writes about those factors.

Comment: @jonathanjo your question title said **"self-discharge rate"** AND you were looking in a data sheet to find this (even more evidence that you meant the **self discharge rate**). Your question **is not** about PCB resistance and any atmospheric conditions. If you want to ask about those things I suggest you raise a new question.

Comment: @Andyaka What I'm asking about is the rate at which a capacitor in a circuit will discharge in real life, without any circuitry intended to discharge it.  If "self-discharge" is not the proper term.  I also find that one learns a lot from the perspective of answerers, who often emphasise different things -- for example, in your answer, noting the potential difficulty in measuring, or that there are extended datasheets, which I didn't know about.   I honestly am really grateful for your help and expertise. In passing, you may not intend it but your tone feels aggressive.

Comment: @jonathanjo you said this: *What I'm asking about is the rate at which a capacitor in a circuit will discharge in real life, without any circuitry intended to discharge it* <-- that is **not** the self-discharge rate (if it's in a circuit unless designed very carefully). You won't find that answer in a capacitor data sheet either. If you are concerned about the effect from the PCB then put a cut-out in the PCB across the body of the capacitor to increase creepage distance. If concerned about atmospheric stuff then lacquer the finished PCB in that vital area.

Comment: @jonathanjo if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @jonathanjo if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: "that is not the self-discharge rate" ... what is it?

Comment: The self discharge rate is governed by the capacitance and the insulation resistance. And, as per your question "*Following the capacitor charging rule, \$V = e^{-t/RC}\$, I'm hoping for something like t ≈ 5RC, but don't see what to use for R*" <-- you are looking for R and, that R is the insulation resistance @jonathanjo

Comment: @Andyaka What I'm asking about is the rate at which a capacitor in a circuit will discharge in real life, without any circuitry intended to discharge it. If "self-discharge" is not the proper term, please could you tell me what is.

Comment: The self-discharge rate is governed by the insulation resistance of the dielectric (as stated in my answer) @jonathanjo. In other words, if the circuit you apply it to has infinite insulation resistance then the **self-discharge rate** is the rate at which it discharges in the circuit. If, on the other hand, the circuit in which it is fitted has a finite insulation resistance then this has to be accounted for by the parallel resistance of the insulation resistance of the capacitor and the insulation resistance of the printed circuit board.